# Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_DefaultMediaType()'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I have a method named `GetJSONResponse(...)` and here's an extract:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(httpResponseCode)
            {
                Content = objectToSerialize != null ?
                    new ObjectContent(objectToSerialize.GetType(), objectToSerialize, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType.MediaType)
                    : null
            };
```

Everything runs fine right up to when this method is called, then I get this error **before the method is entered** (perhaps ASP.NET compiles methods as needed?):

> Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_DefaultMediaType()'.

Originally I thought that a name space was missing from the web.config file (for the views), which I tried to add, but it didn't solve anything - then I realized I'm actually calling it via a WebAPI controller 'Get' method (not a view). The DLLs needed exist (copy to local is true), but this still seems to fail. It's quite obvious the error means a method cannot be found, but it compiles and launches fine since the c# file correctly references the type without issues ... any ideas?

Comment: Is the version of `System.Net.Http.Formatting` that you have at runtime the same version that you are compiling against?

Comment: I have "copy to local" as true, and after manually wiping out the bin & obj folders, yes, they are the same. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the issue: I had a duplicate dependent reference in the main web.config file:

Wrong One:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http"
        publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Right One:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http"
        publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

The correct one was much farther down the list so I didn't notice it was a duplicate. ;)

... come to think of it, it's also why the [API Help Page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/) had an issue. `ApiDescriptionExtensions.GetFriendlyId()` failed to be compiled and run due to this issue as well, but it works now. ;) Caused this error: *Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpMethod System.Web.Http.Description.ApiDescription.get_HttpMethod()'.*

Comment: FWIW, my API Help Page was giving the "get_HttpMethod() not found" error. But my web config didn't have any binding redirects for System.Net.Http. I added the redirect shown in this post, and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I unistalled the NuGet packages relative to the RC version and installed the the new one it will take new version.I think This solve the problem

Comment: In my case I was copying a project to reuse it for another and must have change the .net version to 4.5,  I also updated the packages, but somehow the old dependency setting still got stuck in the web.config for some reason. :/ Of course the trick is knowing that *that* is the issue in the first place.  Once known, it's easy to fix. ;)